# getting error during user logout in laravel using postman

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

Trying to logout a logged in user using postman in laravel **sanctum**.

But error appearing like below:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteFileRegistrar::{closure}() must be an instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Illuminate\\Routing\\Router given, called in E:\\Projects\\crowdFunding\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php on line 423"
```

Things I have done:

1. included `accept:application/json` in postman
2. included bearer token
3. My logout code in controller:

   ```
   return response()->json([
       'message' => 'logged out'
   ]);
   ```

But not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may update logout method as below in your controller.

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $request->user()->tokens()->delete();
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'logged out'
    ]);
}
```